# Object required error when performing For Each loop VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and have encountered this problem when attempting a For Each loop. I have wrapped my head around this for quite some time and couldn't find any answers on this forum.

I suspect it's a silly mistake and would really appreciate it if I could get some help. Thanks alot in advance!

```
Sub AngleAndEComparison()

    Dim rngAngle As Range
    Dim Nrow As Integer
    Dim n#, placeholder#

    Nrow = 1
    n = 0
    Set rngAngle = Intersect(Columns(5), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    ' Set rngAngle = ActiveSheet.Columns(5)
    For Each cell In rngAngle
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            If Range("E" & Nrow).Value > 75 And Range("E" & Nrow).Value < 105 Then 
                placeholder = 1
            If Range("G" & Nrow).Value >= 3 And placeholder = 1 Then
                    n = n + 1
                    cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 36
                    cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 36
                    placeholder = 0
            End If
            Nrow = Nrow + 1
        End If
    Next

    ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 11).Value = n
    ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 10).Value = "Elongated Cells within 15°:"
End Sub
```

Comment: In which line you are getting error ..?

Comment: I am getting an error in this line:                                  For Each cell In rngAngle

Comment: I'd try qualifying all ranges, for example in one case it's `ActiveSheet.Columns(5)` and in another it's just `Column5`. Also, try creating a worksheet variable and setting it to `ActiveSheet` at the beginning of your code. That way if another sheet is activated your code is still pointing at the sheet referred to by the variable.

Comment: Is `rngAngle` an object? i.e. did the code `Set rngAngle = Intersect(Columns(5), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)` actually return anything?

Comment: I've re-formatted your code and noticed that you have 1 floating IF statement when you try to assign value in `placeholder`. Can you fix that and retry your code. Also why execute `cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 36` twice? Btw, if the way I edited your code is different from what it is, just update it. I just copied it from your original post and made some indentions.

Comment: Assuming it's a valid range, shouldn't it be For Each cell In rngAngle.Cells?

Comment: Is cell even declared?

Comment: @VBlades You can omit `.Cells`. It works the same way. As for declaring `cell` variable, it is not required as well as long as OP is not forcing variable declaration. AFAIK, that's how VBA is.

Comment: Looks like @VBlades has hit the nail on the head - you haven't declared `cell` before using it in the loop. Assuming your module has `Option Explicit` enabled, this will raise an error.

Comment: @citizenkong This would raise a compile error (variable not defined). Since the OP says that the error is raised in this line I believe it is a `Run-time error 424: Object required`.

Comment: @ioannis you're right, it's not that. In that case @ElectricLlama's question is the best line of inquiry - are there any cells in `Intersect(Columns(5), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)`?

Comment: I'm relatively sure Option Explicit is not in effect and therefore no compile error.  To me, the cell reference and rngAngle are the two suspects.  Maybe a breakpoint on that line and interrogate the Locals to see what they look like.

Answer (score 1):

Before working with a `Range` object you have set using a function, you should always check that the `Range` object was not set to `Nothing`. In this case below the code will exit if `Intersect` returned `Nothing`

```
Set rngAngle = Intersect(Columns(5), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
' Set rngAngle = ActiveSheet.Columns(5)
If rngAngle Is not Nothing Then 
    Exit Sub
```

Also as others have noted you have a missing `End If`

Answer (score 0):

`Dim Cell as Range` .

and one `End if` is missing , or you must place `then placeholder = 1` on the same line.

before the `for each cell` loop, you can add a `if not rngAngle is nothing then`